# Flutter takePicture() function does not take an image path as stated in the Flutter docs

Tags: flutter, camera, android-camera

I am currently trying to code a camera app, which captures an image and displays it through a separate widget. For that I use the Flutter docs [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera#complete-example). This is the  the full code.

```
    import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' show join;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  // Ensure that plugin services are initialized so that `availableCameras()`
  // can be called before `runApp()`
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Obtain a list of the available cameras on the device.
  final cameras = await availableCameras();

  // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
  final firstCamera = cameras.first;

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: TakePictureScreen(
        // Pass the appropriate camera to the TakePictureScreen widget.
        camera: firstCamera,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

// A screen that allows users to take a picture using a given camera.
class TakePictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final CameraDescription camera;

  const TakePictureScreen({
    Key key,
    @required this.camera,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  TakePictureScreenState createState() => TakePictureScreenState();
}

class TakePictureScreenState extends State<TakePictureScreen> {
  CameraController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // To display the current output from the Camera,
    // create a CameraController.
    _controller = CameraController(
      // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
      widget.camera,
      // Define the resolution to use.
      ResolutionPreset.medium,
    );

    // Next, initialize the controller. This returns a Future.
    _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Dispose of the controller when the widget is disposed.
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Take a picture')),
      // Wait until the controller is initialized before displaying the
      // camera preview. Use a FutureBuilder to display a loading spinner
      // until the controller has finished initializing.
      body: FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: _initializeControllerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            // If the Future is complete, display the preview.
            return CameraPreview(_controller);
          } else {
            // Otherwise, display a loading indicator.
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
        // Provide an onPressed callback.
        onPressed: () async {
          // Take the Picture in a try / catch block. If anything goes wrong,
          // catch the error.
          try {
            // Ensure that the camera is initialized.
            await _initializeControllerFuture;

            // Construct the path where the image should be saved using the
            // pattern package.
            final path = join(
              // Store the picture in the temp directory.
              // Find the temp directory using the `path_provider` plugin.
              (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
              '${DateTime.now()}.png',
            );

            // Attempt to take a picture and log where it's been saved.
            await _controller.takePicture(path);

            // If the picture was taken, display it on a new screen.
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => DisplayPictureScreen(imagePath: path),
              ),
            );
          } catch (e) {
            // If an error occurs, log the error to the console.
            print(e);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

// A widget that displays the picture taken by the user.
class DisplayPictureScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath;

  const DisplayPictureScreen({Key key, this.imagePath}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Display the Picture')),
      // The image is stored as a file on the device. Use the `Image.file`
      // constructor with the given path to display the image.
      body: Image.file(File(imagePath)),
    );
  }
}
```

Now the `takePicture()` function should take `path` as an argument, which is not the case.

**How should I handle this error to save the image properly and then get the path of the image to display it?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the whole code of your Page ?

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. What type of errors are you encountering ?

Comment: After I first press the button to take the picture nothing happens. When I press it a second time, I get this error: I/flutter (11480): CameraException(Previous capture has not returned yet., takePicture was called before the previous capture returned.)

Comment: It seems like the takePicture() function is never fully executed.

Comment: You are running on a real device or on Emulator ?

Comment: I am running it on an emulator.

Comment: This may be your issue. You are already been prompted for Camera Permission grant ?

Comment: Yes when I first tested the app, it asked me for the camera permission. I will try it on a real device.

Comment: It does not work on a real device either..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit late, but maybe this will help other to use the last camera version.
The controller -> takePicture() method return a XFile and XFile object have a method saveTo()

```
      XFile picture = await controller.takePicture();
      picture.saveTo(filePath);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code will work with this version of the camera plugin

```
dependencies:
  camera: 0.5.8+17
```

Since version 0.6.x takePicture has no parameter. If you want to run it with the latest plugin version, take a look at the current [example.](https://pub.dev/packages/camera/example)

Comment: Yes, that solved my problem! Also thanks for the example with the newest version, I will look into it!

Comment: I am using camera ^0.7.0 version and app is being crashed when "Controller.takePicture()" function is called. What is the issue and solution? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: same as me. i have use a latest version. but, i got freeze capture when switch camera from back camera into front camera. also i share my issue on my issue on stackoverflow. probably, you can see on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68867327/flutter-camera-give-an-error-disposed-when-switch-toggle-camera