# Using camera package in flutter not getting picture clicked and preview

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

The camera package I am using is:
camera:
git:
url: https://github.com/flutter/plugins.git
path: packages/camera/camera
ref: cfa709835ab85702ee8a9ed24bbe7a3fe736c3f5

The `code` is:

```
try {
     final path =
      join((await getTemporaryDirectory()).path, '${DateTime.now()}.png');
      await controller.takePicture(**path**); 
       Navigator.push(
        context,
         MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => PreviewScreen(
           imgPath: path,
                   )),
                 );
```

Same code is working fine in different project but whenever I am implementing it to existing one getting `error`:

```
Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.  Try removing the extra argument.
```

on line number 4 of code, the bold text **path*

When I am removing the **path from there,
The console output after triggering function is:

```
 console output: I/flutter (13243): Error:Previous capture has not returned yet.
I/flutter (13243): Error message : takePicture was called before the previous capture returned.
I/flutter (13243): Error:Previous capture has not returned yet.
I/flutter (13243): Error message : takePicture was called before the previous capture returned.
```

Please help.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Please, mention your camara package version. I think It may be change method parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 0.6.x takePicture has no parameter. If you want to run it with the latest plugin version, take a look at the current example.

Please, [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65424123/11427294) for more information.

Comment: Thank you sir, worked for me. :) Also this was the first ever question I have posted on this platform and within 24 hors, it solved my problem.
Thanks once again

Comment: Your wel come @YoGi :)