# Flutter Camera give an error disposed when switch toggle camera

Tags: flutter, dart

i have ask something about camera plugin official by flutter google.

I got a message error like this when i switch camera from back camera into front camera.

[image]

i have try to delete this code

```
Future initController() async {
if(controller != null) {
await controller.disposed(); //this code where i have deleted from initController()
}
...
}
```

but. it give an error like this

```
I/flutter (28913): CameraException(captureTimeout, Picture capture request timed out)
E/CameraCaptureSession(28913): Session 0: Exception while stopping repeating: 
E/CameraCaptureSession(28913): android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): The camera device has encountered a serious error
```

i didn't use image_picker plugin in this case because i have issued on Xiaomi Mi A1 crashed when capture a image in this device. because of that, i was using a official camera plugin by flutter.but, it give me an error.

do you know about my case? I'm very enjoy if you can tell me what's the problem on my case.thank you very much

also i have used camera plugin version 0.8.1+7

Comment: Did you solved this issue?

Comment: i was try on below version of android such as android oreo and android pie. it still stable. maybe, it's bug only for android 11 user